# Does Raspberry Pi hold any data without a SD card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-3

I need to do a IOT project with my pi-3 as a homework assignment, but I have an unexpected problem.

My friends and I did exactly the same things to build the operating system and  project, which is using kafka server to communicate each other.

My friends' projects work fine, but mine is giving some errors on the process of using kafka-python. The errors are like `no brokers available` and `no available kafka server`.

Is it possible that the Pi holds data that can cause errors without the SD card? If so, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: That is highly unlikely. You need to find the differences in those two builds and trace the error itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that are stored on the RPi itself, but nothing that could cause your problems. Unless you did something extraordinarily weird to the RPi, that storage space can't be accessed normally.

It is far more likely that there is something wrong with your build.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the working SD card into the other Pi. This will show if you have a problem with the SD card, or specific to the hardware. All that is specific to the hardware will be things like the MAC address for the interfaces.

Comment: The VideoCore OS is also stored on the hardware itself, but it's extremely unlikely to be the cause of an issue.